# AppleScript to select the messages from Imap folder on Mail.app

Tags: excel, email, applescript, directory, imap

I need to write an Applescript for Mail.app that will export messages' subjects into an excel worksheet.

The closet code I found online which could do this is as following:

```
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 set theSpamFile to make new workbook
 set theSheet to active sheet of theSpamFile
 set formula of range "B1" of theSheet to "Subject"
 set formula of range "A1" of theSheet to "From"
end tell
tell application "Mail"
 set theRow to 2
 get mailboxes
 set theMessages to messages of junk mailbox
 repeat with aMessage in theMessages
 my SetFrom(sender of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
 my SetSubject(subject of aMessage, theRow, theSheet)
 set theRow to theRow + 1
 end repeat
end tell

on SetFrom(theSender, theRow, theSheet)
 tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 set theRange to "A" & theRow
 set formula of (range theRange) of theSheet to theSender
 end tell
end SetFrom

on SetSubject(theSubject, theRow, theSheet)
 tell application "Microsoft Excel"
 set theRange to "B" & theRow
 set formula of range theRange of theSheet to theSubject
 end tell
end SetSubject
```

These code work fine for the Mailbox junk.

But I don't know how to manipulate the code to select messages within a subfolder of a Imap account in Mail.app.

I have several Imap account in Mail.app. Two gmail account, one iCloud account  and etc. I have also created folds and subfolders under each Imap account.

I want to export the unread messages from the subfolder: it is located at "Google/Supplier/SupplierUpdate"

I have tried to change the selecting line from

```
set theMessages to messages of junk mailbox
```

to

```
 set theMessages to messages of mailbox"[Google]/DobaSupplierUpdate/DobaCancellation"
```

But the script editor keep showing the following message:

```
Mail got an error: Can’t get mailbox "[Google]/DobaSupplierUpdate/DobaCancellation".
```

Any help to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
-- set your email address here to find your account
set targetAccount to first item of (every account whose user name is "xxx@googlemail.com")
-- define the wanted subfolders here starting with deepest level
set theMessages to every message of mailbox "SupplierUpdate" of mailbox "Supplier" of targetAccount whose read status is false
```

Best,
ShooTerKo / Hamburg

Comment: @Ivici An open question is an open question. Why didn‘t you post your solution or just deleted the question if you don‘t want an answer?

Comment: Your answer works really really great!!!  I have to confess that I feel overwhelmed even you gave your code to me. Cause I am brand new to AppleScript.  So I have tried several times to replace them with associate code line.  Finally, I got it.   Really appreciate your help. This would improve my daily work  a lot faster.   Best

Comment: How could I exact particular part from the "subject" of email message? For example, the subject is all in this type:" Tracking info for order 1422474 from UNFI". The only part I need is just the number part "1422474". How could I extract it from subject before input them into  Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I recommend searching for a solution on SO or ask a new question. It's not good to use these comments as threads. Search for something like "Extracting numbers from a string".